# Flutter - I can't get the user's location using (geocoding , geolocator) packages

Tags: flutter

```
    Future<Map<String, dynamic>> determinePosition() async {
  bool serviceEnabled;
  LocationPermission permission;

  // Test if location services are enabled.
  serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
  if (!serviceEnabled) {
    // Location services are not enabled don't continue
    // accessing the position and request users of the
    // App to enable the location services.
    return Future.error('Location services are disabled.');
  }

  permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
  if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
    permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      // Permissions are denied, next time you could try
      // requesting permissions again (this is also where
      // Android's shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale
      // returned true. According to Android guidelines
      // your App should show an explanatory UI now.
      // return Future.error('Location permissions are denied');
      return {
        "message": "Unable to access because you denied the location request",
        "error": true,
      };
    }
  }

  if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
    // Permissions are denied forever, handle appropriately.
    return {
      "message":
      "Location permissions are permanently denied, we cannot request permissions.",
      "error": true,
    };
  }

  // When we reach here, permissions are granted and we can
  // continue accessing the position of the device.
  Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
      desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.bestForNavigation);

  return {
    "position": position,
    "message": "Managed to get the position of the device",
    "error": false,
  };
}

      Future getAddress() async {
    Map<String, dynamic> _determinePosition = await determinePosition();
    if (!_determinePosition["error"]) {
      Position position = _determinePosition["position"];
      List<Placemark> placemarks =
      await placemarkFromCoordinates(position.latitude, position.longitude);
       address =
          "${placemarks.first.street}, ${placemarks.first
          .subLocality}, ${placemarks.first.locality},${placemarks.first.name}";
       print(address);
    } else {
      SnackBar(content: Text(' _determinePosition["message"]'),);
      print(_determinePosition["error"]);
    }
    emit(AppLocationState());

  }
```

This is the code for the two functions used to get the location. I used Cubit for the statemanagment, in which I called the determinPosition function, and I called the getaddress function in the materialapp when using multiproviders.

Here is an illustration of how I called the getaddress function

```
return  MultiBlocProvider(
    providers: [
      BlocProvider(create: (context) =>RegisterCubit()),
      BlocProvider(create: (context) =>LoginCubit()),
      BlocProvider(create: (context) =>AppCubit()..getAddress())

    ],
    child: BlocConsumer<AppCubit, AppState>(
listener: (context, state) {},
builder: (context, state) {
  // ignore: unused_local_variable
  AppCubit cubit = AppCubit.get(context);
  print(address);
  return
    MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        localizationsDelegates: [
          GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        ],
        supportedLocales: [
          Locale("en"),
          Locale("ar"),
        ],
        locale: Locale("ar"),
        home: Verify()



    );
})
);
```

Here is the error message that appears to me when I run the program, how can I fix it?

```
E/flutter ( 3390): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(IO_ERROR, A network error occurred trying to lookup the supplied coordinates (latitude: 37.421998, longitude: -122.084000)., null, null)
E/flutter ( 3390): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:653:7)
E/flutter ( 3390): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:315:18)
E/flutter ( 3390): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 3390): #2      MethodChannelGeocoding.placemarkFromCoordinates (package:geocoding_platform_interface/src/implementations/method_channel_geocoding.dart:56:24)
E/flutter ( 3390): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 3390): #3      AppCubit.getAddress (package:google_solution/shared/cubit/app_cubit.dart:21:7)
E/flutter ( 3390): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 3390):
```

Comment: May be you forgot to include your error statement.

Comment: I added a picture of it, but I don't know why it didn't appear with the question. I apologize for that..I added it as a text.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the error log it might be due to not having the proper internet connectivity. Please ensure that an active internet connection is available in the device with the application.

In addition to that to handle this exception, you could have the below code modification

```
Future getAddress() async { 
  try {
    Map<String, dynamic> _determinePosition = await determinePosition();
    if (!_determinePosition["error"]) {
      Position position = _determinePosition["position"];
      List<Placemark> placemarks =
          await placemarkFromCoordinates(position.latitude, position.longitude);
      address =
          "${placemarks.first.street}, ${placemarks.first.subLocality}, ${placemarks.first.locality},${placemarks.first.name}";
      print(address);
    } else {
      print(_determinePosition["message"]);
      address = "Default Location"; // Provide a default location here.
    }
    emit(AppLocationState());
 } catch (e) {
  print("Error fetching location: $e");
  address =
    "Default Location"; // Provide a default location in case of an error.
  emit(AppLocationState());
}}
```